# How to execute jar files from another folder

Tags: java, node.js, jar, minecraft

Im currently building a NodeJS Webinterface for Minecraft. Currently I'm struggeling with getting the Server started...
My current folder layout is the following

```
./node_modules
./server
./views
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Every time I'm starting the server which is located in ./servers, the eula.txt and other server files are generated in the home directory with my app.js and so on. Is there a way how I could change the directory where the files are located?

Edit (Shortend Version of the code that executes the jar):

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('java -jar ' + './server/spigot-1.13.2.jar', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err)
    throw err;
console.log(stdout);
console.log(stderr);
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code that is running the jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spawn you can provide a working directory.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const mc = spawn('java', ['-Xmx1024M', '-Xms1024M', '-jar', './server/spigot-1.13.2.jar', 'nogui'], { cwd: './new-server/' });


mc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

mc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

mc.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems like you can also do this with exec like this:

```
exec('java -jar ' + './server/spigot-1.13.2.jar', { cwd: './test-server' }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err)
    throw err;
console.log(stdout);
console.log(stderr);
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for you answer. I'm having a problem finding the jar file with your provided code. With the old code the jar file is beeing executed with no problem but I with your code I get the error that it is unable to find the jar

Comment: That is because the cwd has changed. The thing with minecraft bukkit is that the folder it is executed in will generate all the required files. So you would actually like to create a new folder and move the jar file over there (or copy it), after that run it with the above command and you should be good to go.